# How to fill a path figure comprised of arcs completely with VectSharp?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create the figure of a [tangent ogive nose cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nose_cone_design) using [VectSharp](https://giorgiobianchini.com/VectSharp/) 2.4. To achieve that, I'm combining two arcs together and adding a backside to complete the shape.

When I stroke and fill the path, I get the following result:

[image: nose cone]

The code I'm using to create the figure looks like:

```
path.MoveTo(pTopLeft);
path.Arc(pTopCircleCentre, radius, topStartAngle, topEndAngle);
path.Arc(pBottomCircleCentre, radius, bottomEndAngle, bottomStartAngle);
path.LineTo(pTopLeft);
path.Close();
```

As you can see in the figure above, only the arcs get filled, not the whole figure. I expected that by closing the path, it would be seen as a single path figure, but apparently, it's not. How would I be able to achieve filling this type of shape?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
// grpahics object is your page's graphics object
graphics.FillPath(path, Colours.Green);
```

Here is the documentation link having an example when using `Arc`.

https://giorgiobianchini.com/VectSharp/arbitrary_shapes.html#drawing-a-circular-arc